# Click Event is not Working When Data loads Dynamic in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Scenario

- i need when user click on image , image should toggle.(only before page d"nt load), say landing page.
- then user scroll browser (load more stories ) then click on image doesn"t fires.
- i have debug issue find i have used click function on class so when page loads browser assign class to html (click works).
- then scroll load more then it browser does n"t assign class to rendering html therefore click w"nt work.

js code

```
  var eventData = {};
$(document).ready(function(){

  if (localStorage.getItem('eventData') !== null) {
    $.each(eventData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('eventData')), function(id){
        $('#'+id).addClass('faved');
    });
  }
  });
  $('.favourate_dextop').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (eventData[this.id] !== undefined) {
        delete eventData[this.id];
    }else{
        eventData[this.id] = $(this).data();
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('faved');
    localStorage.setItem('eventData', JSON.stringify(eventData));
    console.log(eventData);
});
```

html code

```
        <div  style="display:block; float:right; width:auto; color:#7c7c7c;">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="favourate_dextop" title="Add to Favorites" id="fav'.$data[$k]['id'].'"
            data-sess_id="'.$data[$k]['id'].'"
            data-name="'.$name_event.'"
            data-city="'.$event_city.'"
            data-country="'.$event_country.'" 
            data-event_url="'.$event_urls.'" >
            </a>
             </div>
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/o61rqj95/5/

problem

- i need click to be works also when load more  data has been render.
- any suggestion are most welcome.
- click works only before load more .

  Solution i found after googling

  ```
  1. <a href="javascript:functionname(this);">

  2. in html file call function name.
  ```

  function functionname(item)
  {
   alert("test");
  }
- then also alert don"t works.

working solution

```
var eventData = {};
 $(document).ready(function(){

if (localStorage.getItem('eventData') !== null) {
    $.each(eventData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('eventData')), function(id){
        $('#'+id).addClass('faved');
    });
}
$('.favourate_dextop').on("click", function(e){ favorite(this); });
```

});

```
function favorite(item){
console.dir(item);

    if (eventData[item.id] !== undefined) {
        delete eventData[item.id];
    }else{
        eventData[item.id] = $(item).data();
    }
    $(item).toggleClass('faved');
    localStorage.setItem('eventData', JSON.stringify(eventData));
    console.log(eventData);

}
```

Comment: Delegate the Click. https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: you need to bind the event to the target element because it is loading dynamically, meaning when the initial page loads, the target element is not even available in the DOM structure

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
$('body').on('click','.favourate_dextop',function(e){
  //code
});
```

Instead of

```
$('.favourate_dextop').click(function(e){
 //code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Select Parent element first As per bellow example

```
<div id="dvParent">
    <span> Span 1 </span>
    <span> Span 2. </span>
</div>
```

to attach click event to span element, we can use any of these codes:

```
// Ex 1.
$('div#dvParent').on('click', 'span', function () {};

// Ex 2.
$(document).on('click','div#dvParent span', function(){};

// Ex 3.
$('parent_Selector').on('click', '.selector', function(event) {
    /* Act on the event */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, `$(selector).click()` events work for static html only. To deal with dynamic html you have to use `.on()` like:

```
$('static_parent').on('click','.favourate_dextop',function(e){
  //your code
});
```

or

```
$('body').on('click','.favourate_dextop',function(e){
  //your code
});
```

or

```
$(document).on('click','.favourate_dextop',function(e){
  //your code
});
```